# SQL Agent Job Modification Minimum Permission Requirement

Tags: sql-server-2016, jobs, system-administration, sql-agent

I need permission to modify other users job in sql server 2016 in dev environment but DBA team is saying they can't give me sysadmin role. So is their any other option present without sysadmin so that I can modify jobs created by other users.

Answer (score 1):

Directly, no. But you can ask your sysadmins to create a wrapper stored procedure, which calls `msdb.dbo.sp_update_job`, has the same parameters and executes as privileged user. And then to give you, or `SQLAgentOperatorRole` (if everybody should be able to modify not only his jobs, but all) rights to execute it. In the example below, the stored procedure is executed by owner. It assumes its owner will be sysadmin. If needed, you can change this and for example specify particular login instead.

```
USE msdb
GO
CREATE PROC [dbo].[sp_update_job_for_non_admins]
      @job_id                       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = NULL,
      @job_name                     sysname          = NULL,
      @new_name                     sysname          = NULL,
      @enabled                      TINYINT          = NULL,
      @description                  NVARCHAR(512)    = NULL,
      @start_step_id                INT              = NULL,
      @category_name                sysname          = NULL,
      @owner_login_name             sysname          = NULL,
      @notify_level_eventlog        INT              = NULL,
      @notify_level_email           INT              = NULL,
      @notify_level_netsend         INT              = NULL,
      @notify_level_page            INT              = NULL,
      @notify_email_operator_name   sysname          = NULL,
      @notify_netsend_operator_name sysname          = NULL,
      @notify_page_operator_name    sysname          = NULL,
      @delete_level                 INT              = NULL,
      @automatic_post               BIT              = 1
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
BEGIN
   EXEC dbo.sp_update_job
      @job_id
      ,@job_name
      ,@new_name
      ,@enabled
      ,@description
      ,@start_step_id
      ,@category_name
      ,@owner_login_name
      ,@notify_level_eventlog
      ,@notify_level_email
      ,@notify_level_netsend
      ,@notify_level_page
      ,@notify_email_operator_name
      ,@notify_netsend_operator_name
      ,@notify_page_operator_name
      ,@delete_level
      ,@automatic_post
END
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[sp_update_job_for_non_admins] TO [SQLAgentOperatorRole]
```

[The credits for this solution are for Boris Hristov](https://borishristov.com/blog/modifying-not-owned-sql-agent-jobs-without-being-a-sysadmin/).

Comment: Thanks @andrey for the answer, so we have to do some work around no role based option?

Comment: No, there is no role in SQL Server, other than highly privileged sysadmin, which allows you to modify other people's stuff.